# Entity Framework and SQL Server table properties

Tags: entity-framework-4, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5

We have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with several tables and each table has a number of triggers. On one of the columns, we'll call this Person.Age we have a default value, so that if I don't explicitly supply a value it defaults to "18".

```
    create table PERSON
(
id                              int             IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
age                             char(2)         DEFAULT '18',
Name                            char(40),   
);
```

I am using EntityFramework 4.0 (and have also tried 5.0) and Visual Studio 2010, to load and select from the database. Whenever I insert into the table using the following statement, it is inserting a row, but it isn't completing the default value:

```
var person = new Person
{
   Name = "Peter"
};

using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
            {
                ctx.PERSON.AddObject(person);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
```

This will result in a row with a Name of Peter, but the Age will be set to null - and not my default of 18.

When I refresh/load my EDMX file I can only seem to import simple tables and views and there doesn't appear to be an option for importing the properties - although I would have thought this was done by default? Any ideas why the default properties aren't firing?

Also, I have triggers defined in SQL Server so that when a new row is inserted into PERSON, an additional table gets updated. Again this works if I run the SQL direct against the database, but doesn't work if I execute through Visual Studio using EntityFramework.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

EF will explicitly set the columns to values you passed. Since, when you created a Person entity, the value for age will be by default set to null EF will send a command in which it will set the column value to null. Set the default value in the ctor if you want to have the default value (otherwise the default value is null for reference properties and default(T) for value type properties (e.g. int)).

The EF designer brings all the columns from the database and create a model with entities that have properties coresponding to the values to the tables and columns it reversed engieneered. You can then go and tweak your model in the designer - for instance you can remove properties you don't want.

I don't know what "does not work" means for you in case of the triggers - it probably depends on your expectation. EF just sends a command to the database. So if you send the same Sql command as the EF sends it should "not work" in the same way. Having said that EF is database agnostic and is not aware of DB magic like triggers. Also the communication is one way only from EF to the DB. So, if you expect that the database notifies the EF about something then it will not work. There are no means for doing this.